# Null PointerException on TESTNG ,pagefactory

Tags: java, testng, page-factory

**LoginPage.Java**

```
package TestCases;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import ObjectRepository.EnterCredentialsRepository;
import ObjectRepository.LaunchURLRepository;

public class LoginPage {

    WebDriver driver;
    LaunchURLRepository lpR;
    //EnterCredentialsRepository ecR;

    @Test
    public void LoginPageApp () throws Exception
    {

            lpR = new LaunchURLRepository();
            lpR.LaunchDriver();
            lpR.getURL();

            //ecR = new EnterCredentialsRepository();
            lpR.Username.sendKeys("admin");
            lpR.Password.sendKeys("admin");

    }


}
```

**LaunchURLRepository.java**

```
package ObjectRepository;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

public class LaunchURLRepository {

    public static WebDriver driver;
    WebDriverWait wait;
    public static String url = "https://www.google.com";

    @FindBy(id="txtUserID")
    public WebElement Username;

    @FindBy(css="input#txtPassword")
    public WebElement Password;


    public WebDriver LaunchDriver()
    {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Drivers\\chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();

        wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,10);

        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        return driver;
    }

    public void getURL()
    {
        driver.get(url);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
    }

    public LaunchURLRepository()
    {
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);

    }

}
```

I am getting below NullPointer execption.... Please Help

```
FAILED: LoginPageApp
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.pagefactory.DefaultElementLocator.findElement(DefaultElementLocator.java:69)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.pagefactory.internal.LocatingElementHandler.invoke(LocatingElementHandler.java:38)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy7.sendKeys(Unknown Source)
    at TestCases.LoginPage.LoginPageApp(LoginPage.java:26)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:124)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:580)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:716)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:988)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:648)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:505)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:455)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:450)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:415)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:364)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:84)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1208)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1137)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1049)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1017)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:114)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)


===============================================
    Default test
    Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
===============================================


===============================================
Default suite
Total tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
===============================================
```

Answer (score 1):

Selenium will instantiate a WebElement object when you call `PageFactory.initElements(driver, LaunchURLRepository.class)`

Before this statement, any interaction with the WebElement attributes will result in a NullPointerException.

More details on the [Selenium Wiki](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/PageFactory) and the Javadoc of this method [here](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/M_OpenQA_Selenium_Support_PageObjects_PageFactory_InitElements.htm).